# Yii-user + RESTapi

Tags: rest, yii, yii-extensions

im using [yii-user](http://yii-user.2mx.org/en), also im using [restfullyii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/).

The problem is i cant make it work.

Posts page: **index.php/posts/** , and *index.php/api/posts* works fine

When im trying to get user data via *index.php/api/user* it returns 404 error (Unable to resolve the request "user/REST.GET")

Need to fix it as soon as possible, a way to get dat afrom /user/ via visiting /api/users page in JSON, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a UserController? Please add your code if you have. Make sure the filename of your controller is "UserController.php". It is case sensitive.

Comment: [UserController.php](http://pastebin.com/fBA86Xx2), same code in [PostController.php](http://pastebin.com/NUCN11iv) works fine. Here's the restfullyii [routes.php](http://pastebin.com/UZdMcYJG)